# Trying to attain a deeper level of understanding the Quran

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, sadaqah, munafiq

I've had read the Quran in Arabic and suddenly realised that "مُنَافِقِينَ" (hypocrites) and يُنفِقُونَ (spend) have the same root. Is it so? And if yes, what unites them?

**Why do I ask?**

Because I try to understand the Quran in its original form - in Arabic. And translation to your first language does not reveal the hidden and narrow connections between different Arabic words who are actually close.

And bringing the light to it gives much deeper connections to the Book of Allah and may even help you seeing linguistic miracles!

Peace and welcome to the journey towards the word of God!

---

O, my Lord!

Surely, I wanna understand Your word!

I wanna meet you

And be pleased

I testify this!

Comment: MashaAllah. Yes, **Nifaq** (hypocrisy) and **Infaq** (spend) both come from the same root word N-F-Q (**ن ف ق**). As for the connections, best to learn these from scholars with a mastery in Arabic.